# Git log gives 400 500 as committer name

Tags: git, github, git-log

**Git log gives 400,500 as the committer name**

> I have a powershell script which run the git diff between 2 branches and gives me the output in a file.

```
git diff generates the diff file using   git diff --summary --name-status --diff-filter=ADMRCT  $branch1..$branch2 | Out-File $temp
```

> $temp file is iterated and every line is read to get the last committer name and last committed date from git log since this info is not provided by **git diff**

```
foreach ($obj in $temp) {
       $file =$obj.FileName
       $gitoutput =  git log -1 --format=%cd-%cn "$file" }
```

Output attached.[SampleForReference](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4kvbO.jpg)
`

Comment: Can you give two `git log` outputs of a file where this is happening? One with the first few lines of `git log` and one with the output of your command.

Comment: Also, can you please fix the formatting of your post?

Comment: Hi Nils, I have formatted my question ,Can you please help me ?

Answer (score 1):

`%cd` gives the committer date. If you just want the name, use `%cn` or `%cN` alone.

Without looking at your exact output, I am guessing the 400 500 you see if the timezone in the date.

Comment: Hi Manojds,I have updated my query and also added the sampleoutput for reference

Comment: @SwatiJha - you can see that the fault is in the logic used to separate the fields that you are showing in the screenshot. The timezone is missing wherever you have the actual name.

Comment: Didnt really understand ,how do I fix this ?